# Why does GTK beep when calling `gtk_entry_set_text` (while resizing a window)?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I'm the maintainer of [xnec2c](https://www.xnec2c.org/) and we found that this code was causing xnec2c to beep through the PC speaker (excessively and annoyingly) while resizing a window or rotating an object:

```c
      snprintf( txt, sizeof(txt), "%7.2f", Viewer_Gain(proj_params, calc_data.freq_step) );
      gtk_entry_set_text( GTK_ENTRY(Builder_Get_Object(builder, widget)), txt );
```

Why would `gtk_entry_set_text` beep?

Comment: In case its useful to others, see [this thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=261938), which has a suggested work-around for a similar issue (though it didn't solve the problem in this case).

Answer (score 0):

After much troubleshooting, the `"%7.2f"` was creating text that was too long for the text field defined by `widget` (NB, `widget` is a `gchar[]` string naming the widget, not a widget object).

The length of `txt` exceeded the text field's `max-length` as defined by the Glade XML, so `gtk_entry_set_text` would trigger a beep event every time the widget text was updated.

In case it helps someone else, this was the fix:

```
-      snprintf( txt, sizeof(txt), "%7.2f", Viewer_Gain(proj_params, calc_data.freq_step) );
+      snprintf( txt, sizeof(txt)-1, "%.2f", Viewer_Gain(proj_params, calc_data.freq_step) );
       gtk_entry_set_text( GTK_ENTRY(Builder_Get_Object(builder, widget)), txt );
...
-        <property name="max-length">6</property>
+        <property name="max-length">9</property>
```

and [this is the commit](https://github.com/KJ7LNW/xnec2c/commit/7bba2b40b9ccaf27f7367d61c48588a141e0a1be) that solved our issue if you wish to review the entire thing.